# How can I use order by rand() and group by simultaneously?

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

My query is like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT a.*, b.name AS store_name
    FROM products a
    JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
    WHERE a.status = 1
    ORDER BY RAND()
) AS product
GROUP BY store_id LIMIT 100
```

When the query is executed, the result is the same. It is not random.

If I delete group by then it works

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You  have  wrong `group by` in your query, also `order by` in subquery, doesn't  makes sense in this case

Comment: Do you even know what `GROUP BY` does? What gives you the idea to combine it with `SELECT *` or with `LIMIT 100`? That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: GROUP BY can only be used when you have an aggregate function (SUM(), AVG(), COUNT(), etc.) in your columns list. You have none of those. Find a SQL tutorial and read about aggregation and GROUP BY.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Group by is used along with count,sum,avg... function 
you can not use it alone

for exp :

table

**id      result**

1       YES

2       NO

3       NO

3       YES

2       YES

2       NO

```
SELECT id,count(*) as nb
FROM table
GROUP BY (id)
```

the output will be

**id nb**

1  1

2  3

3  3

the grouped by 'id' always has to appear it the query result